# How to fully style spinner within action bar sherlock?

Tags: actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar, spinner, android-theme

I've been fiddling with styling the spinner for actionbarsherlock. (I know there is a lot of questions like this, and I have tried several - but no luck).

Using this: http://krishnalalstha.wordpress.com/2013/02/13/223/

Here's what I want to do:

My actionbar is dark - almost greyish. Therefore the spinner item should have a "white" text color. When you click the spinner and the items drop down- I want those "items" to have a black text color.

I created my own custom spinner layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/name_view"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:paddingLeft="5dp"
   android:paddingRight ="5dp"
   android:paddingTop="5dp"
   android:paddingBottom ="5dp"
   android:text="Medium Text"
   android:textColor = "@color/LightGrey"
   android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium">
</TextView>
```

And this works quite well for the spinner before its clicked and drop down items appear, but when drop down items appear, its barely visible because its all light grey.

This is how I set my adapter with the custom_spinner_layout.xml(TextView) file:

```
ArrayAdapter <String> mSpinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),R.layout.custom_spinner_layout,spinnerArray);
```

This is how I set adapter if I use the styling from link above:

```
ArrayAdapter <String> mSpinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,spinnerArray);
```

I want to use styling instead of creating a custom spinner layout - however it's not working...am I using the wrong android.R.layout resource? The reason why I don't populate my spinner with strings from resources is because it dynamically changes in the application.

Any help is appreciated...